# Why i'm getting error Inconsistent accessibility?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class:

```
class NewsLine
        {
            public string text;
            public string original_time;
            public string link;
        }
```

Then a method:

```
private void AddOnlyNew(List<NewsLine> filtered_lnl)
        {
            NewsLine lnl = new NewsLine();
            for (int x = 0; x < filtered_lnl.Count; x++)
            {
                if (!AllNews.Contains(filtered_lnl[x]))
                {
                    AllNews.Add(filtered_lnl[x]);
                }
                for (int y = 0; y < AllNews.Count; y++)
                {
                    Compare(filtered_lnl[x], AllNews[y]);
                }
            }            
        }
```

And the Compare method:

```
public static int Compare(NewsLine n1, NewsLine n2)
        {
            if (n1.text != n2.text)
                return string.Compare(n1.text, n2.text);
            else if (n1.original_time != n2.original_time)
                return string.Compare(n1.original_time, n2.original_time);
            else
                return string.Compare(n1.link, n2.link);
        }
```

Om the Compare of the Cpmare method i'm getting two errors:

Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.NewsLine' is less accessible than method 'ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.Compare(ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.NewsLine, ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.NewsLine)'

And

Error   2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.NewsLine' is less accessible than method 'ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.Compare(ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.NewsLine, ScrollLabelTest.ListsExtractions.NewsLine)'

Comment: How are these error messages not as clear as possible. Look at the access modifier of your `NewsLine` class and compare it to the one of the `Compare` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `Compare` method is public and accepts parameters of `NewsLine` which is internal.  So either change `Compare` to be internal or make `NewsLine` public.

Comment: Internal not Private. Edit: :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your Compare method is public, but your class Newsline is private or internal; it is less accessible than Compare(). That's where "inconsistent" comes from. Make Newsline public and this should work.